# How do I use setState on a bool of which the initial value isn't know until after the widget build method runs? Flutter Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, setstate

For a post and comments system, I have a Response class where the status field determines if the response is 'published' or 'hidden'.

I use a FirestoreListView to display these responses. If a response has its status set to hidden, it should be collapsed else it should just show. For this, I have a bool responseVisible. When the responses are first read, I initialize responseVisible as follows:

```
bool responseVisible = response.status == 'published';
```

Then I use 2 Visibility widgets. The normal one is visible when responseVisible is true and the collapsed version is visible when responseVisible is false.

This works perfectly. Responses with status published are shown and those with status hidden have a response collapsed message.

But now I want to add a button to open collapsed responses. For this, I use setState to change responseVisible to true. But since I am initializing responseVisible in the widget build method, the setState value keeps being overwritten by the initialization value.

Normally, I would just take the responseVisible bool out of the widget build method and initialize it there but in this case, I can't because the response's status isn't known to me before the widget build method runs.

So now I'm stuck. How can I rewrite this to make opening a collapsed response work?

```
class Response {
  final String postId;
  final String? responseId;
  final UserProfile author;
  final String content;
  final DateTime datePublished;
  DateTime? dateModified;
  final Map<String, Reply>? replies;
  final String status;
  final String statusContext;

  Response({
    required this.postId,
    this.responseId,
    required this.author,
    required this.content,
    required this.datePublished,
    this.dateModified,
    this.replies,
    required this.status,
    required this.statusContext,
  });
```

```
class ResponseStream extends StatefulWidget {
  ResponseStream({Key? key, required this.post, this.height}) : super(key: key);

  final Post post;
  double? height = 400;

  @override
  State<ResponseStream> createState() => _ResponseStreamState();
}

class _ResponseStreamState extends State<ResponseStream> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final responsesCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('posts')
        .doc(widget.post.postId)
        .collection('responses')
        .orderBy('datePublished', descending: true)
        .withConverter<Response>(
          fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => Response.fromJson(snapshot.id, snapshot.data()!),
          toFirestore: (responses, _) => responses.toJson(),
        );

    return SizedBox(
      height: widget.height,
      child: FirestoreListView<Response>(
          query: responsesCollection,
          itemBuilder: (context, snapshot) {
            Response response = snapshot.data();
            bool responseVisible = response.status == 'published';

            return ListTile(
              title: Text(
                "${response.author.name} ~ ${fs.format(response.datePublished)}",
              ),
              subtitle: Column(
                children: [
                  Visibility(
                    visible: responseVisible,
                    child: Text(response.content),
                  ),
                  Visibility(
                    visible: !responseVisible,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text('This response was collapsed for: ${response.statusContext}.'),
                        GestureDetector(
                          child: const Text("Show Response"),
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              responseVisible = !responseVisible;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I wound up doing is create a separate widget called ResponseDetail. That way I could continue to initialize responseVisible in the main build method and within that put the new ResponseDetail widget which has its own build method with setState() running in there. This way the new widget's call to setState is not overwritten by the outer build method's initialization value.

```
class ResponseDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  ResponseDetail({Key? key, required this.response, required this.responseVisible, required this.ownPost})
      : super(key: key);

  Response response;
  bool responseVisible;
  bool ownPost;

  @override
  State<ResponseDetail> createState() => _ResponseDetailState();
}

class _ResponseDetailState extends State<ResponseDetail> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Visibility(...),
        Visibility(...),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

And then in the outer build method:

```
    ... itemBuilder: (context, snapshot) {
            Response response = snapshot.data();
            bool responseVisible = response.status == 'published';    
            return ListTile(
              title: Text("${response.author.name} ~ fs.format(response.datePublished)}"),
              subtitle: ResponseDetail(response: response, responseVisible: responseVisible, ownPost: ownPost),
        ), 
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about adding the parameter "responseVisible" to the Response class itself, setting its initial value to false, and then modifying it?

Comment: Thanks for answering but that would leave me with the same problem: how to effectively call setState on a field that is being initialized inside the build method. Making a separate widget did the trick as I explained in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Map at the top of your `ResponseStream` Widget to overwrite the existing published values, where the postId maps to the visibility.

```dart
Map<String,bool> responseVisibility = new Map();
```

Set the stored visibilities to the default value if the map does not contain that postId and simply just query the Map.

```dart
if(!responseVisibility.containsKey(response.postId)) responseVisibility[response.postId] = response.status == 'published';

bool responseVisible = responseVisibility[response.postId];
```

Finally, to update the visibility, just update the Map.

```dart
setState(() {
  responseVisibility[response.postId] = !responseVisibility[response.postId];
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. This looks like it might have worked but what I ended up doing was make a separate widget with its own internal build method and then I call setState from there. I explained in my answer below.